# Bind nested object from angular to webapi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, angular6, xml-serialization

I am trying to send data from angular application to "Add" webapi method in xml format. 
I am able to bind normal properties but nested type Phone object is not getting binded.
Please help me to bind Phone object to webapi model.

[image]

Below is my code:-

PatientModel.ts

```
export class Patient {
    PatientId: string;
    FirstName: string;
    Phone: TelephoneNumber;
}

export class TelephoneNumber {
    CellPhone: number;
}
```

Add-Patient.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    PatientId: ['', Validators.required],
    FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
    Phone: this.formBuilder.group({
      CellPhone:['',Validators.pattern("[0-9]\\d{9}")]
    })
  });
};

this.patientService.addPatient(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
       this.router.navigate(['patient']);
  });
```

Patient.service.ts

```
 addPatient(patient: Patient) {
   const postedData =`<Patient  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
   <PatientId>${patient.PatientId}</PatientId>
   <FirstName>${patient.FirstName}</FirstName>
   <Phone>
   <CellPhone  xsi:nil="true">${patient.Phone.CellPhone}</CellPhone>
   </Phone>
  </Patient>`

  let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append('Accept', 'text/xml');

  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+"/add" ,postedData , { headers: 
         httpHeaders });
}
```

add.patient.component.html

```
 <form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <div class="form-group" formGroupName="Phone"> 
      <label for="CellPhone">Cell Phone:</label>
      <input formControlName="CellPhone" placeholder="Cell Phone"  
       class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && 
       f['Phone'].controls['CellPhone'].errors }">
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f['Phone'].controls['CellPhone'].errors" 
               class="invalid-feedback">
          </div>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
 </form>
```

WebApi controller method

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Add(Patient p)
    {
        int response =this._patientService.AddPatient(p);
        if (response == -1)
            return Conflict();
        else
            return Ok("Data posted successfully");
    }
```

Patient class

```
public class Patient
{
    public string PatientId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public TelephoneNumber Phone { get; set; }
}
public class TelephoneNumber
{
    public int? CellPhone { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check network request through Fiddler if all values are getting passed to the Web api server.
If everything is getting passed over the network then please implement Model binder for your complex type

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Add([ModelBinder(typeof(PatientBinder))]Patient p)
    {
    }
```

On how to implement Model binders, please refer below URLs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/parameter-binding-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Checked in fiddler.data is not getting passed in network request.                <Phone>
      <CellPhone  xsi:nil="true">undefined</CellPhone>
   </Phone>